# Datetime presented as 2 input fields assembled back with errors in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a model with such field:

```
/**
 * @var datetimetz
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="effective_from", type="datetimetz", nullable=false)
 */
private $effectiveFrom;
```

in the form builder I present it as:

```
        ->add('effectiveFrom', 'datetime', array(
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_format' => 'Y-MM-dd',
            'with_seconds' => true
        ))
```

So it is rendered as two different input fields.

Let's suppose I've specified `2012-07-31` in the date field and `16:15:18` in the time field.

I press submit and `var_dump()` the entity. The bind date becomes `1970-07-31 16:15:18`. And with any date only `year` is recognized in wrong way :-S

If I don't change date and time widgets - then everything works as expected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is symfony documentation bug.

`yyyy` (lower case) should be used.

I've filled the bug https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/1045 and I hope it will be fixed soon